# Limiting query size with entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

this is a simple question (I think), but I have not been able to find a solution. I know with other types of queries, you can add a limit clause that makes the query only return up to that many results. Is this possible with an entity query?

```
var productQuery = from b in solutionContext.Version
                               where b.Product.ID != 1 && b.VersionNumber == b.Product.ActiveNumber
                               orderby b.Product.LastNumber
                               select b;
```

I just want to make it so this query only returns 25 version objects. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

sure.. for example you can do it like this:

```
var productQuery = from b in solutionContext.Version
                           where b.Product.ID != 1 && b.VersionNumber == b.Product.ActiveNumber
                           orderby b.Product.LastNumber
                           select b;

var limitedProductQuery = productQuery.Take(25);
```

also you may need this for paging results:

```
var pagedProductQuery = productQuery.Skip(25 * page).Take(25)
```

Comment: That's going to select everything from the table before restricting the results in memory.

Comment: David.. no, its not.. Its querable object.. its equivalent to query... It will execute when he will try to get some objects or use ToList method etc.

Comment: @David, what in that original query forces execution?

Comment: @LukaszW.pl, sorry I didn't realise that.

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300906.aspx):

```
var productQuery = (from b in solutionContext.Version
                   where b.Product.ID != 1 
                       && b.VersionNumber == b.Product.ActiveNumber
                   orderby b.Product.LastNumber
                   select b).Take(25);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var productQuery = (from b in solutionContext.Version
                           where b.Product.ID != 1 && b.VersionNumber == b.Product.ActiveNumber
                           orderby b.Product.LastNumber
                           select b).Take(25);
```