# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

Basically I use Entity Framework to query a huge database. I want to return a string list then log it to a text file.

```
List<string> logFilePathFileName = new List<string>();
var query = from c in DBContext.MyTable where condition = something select c;
foreach (var result in query)
{
    filePath = result.FilePath;
    fileName = result.FileName;
    string temp = filePath + "." + fileName;
    logFilePathFileName.Add(temp);
    if(logFilePathFileName.Count %1000 ==0)
        Console.WriteLine(temp+"."+logFilePathFileName.Count);
}
```

However I got an exception when `logFilePathFileName.Count=397000`.
The exception is:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

**UPDATE:**

What I want to use a different query say: select top 1000 then add to the list, but I don't know after 1000 then what?

Comment: Hint: upgrade your RAM :-)

Comment: Can you provide full info about exception with inner exception if any and also stack trace.

Comment: What length is temp typically?

Comment: Memory is 4GB, it is enough...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906891/what-is-the-max-limit-of-data-into-liststring-in-c

Comment: OutOfMemoryException has hardly ever anything to do with physical memory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most probabbly it's not about a `RAM` as is, so increasing your `RAM` or even compiling and running your code in `64` bit machine will not have a positive effect, in this case.

I think it's related to a fact that `.NET` collections are limited to maximum `2GB` RAM space (no difference either `32` or `64` bit).

To resolve this, split your list to much smaller chunks and *most probabbly* your problem will gone.

Just one possible solution:

```
foreach (var result in query)
{
    ....
    if(logFilePathFileName.Count %1000 ==0) {
        Console.WriteLine(temp+"."+logFilePathFileName.Count);
        //WRITE SOMEWHERE YOU NEED 
        logFilePathFileName = new List<string>(); //RESET LIST !|
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want fragment a **query**, you can use `Skip(...)` and `Take(...)`

Just an explanatory example:

```
var fisrt1000 = query.Skip(0).Take(1000);
var second1000 = query.Skip(1000).Take(1000);
```

...
and so  on..

Naturally put it in your iteration and parametrize it based on bounds of data you know or need.

Comment: The question is that the database seems to be died as well because of heavy query.

Comment: So exception you get on *server* ?

Comment: Not yet, may be something else. Please see my update, I want to select top 1000 bulk then iterate the rest, how?

Comment: You ca fragment or your query using *Skip(..)* and *Take(..)*, or get all in one query but fragment list.

Comment: I meant after 1000, how to select 1001-2000 by query? You can't still use select top 1000...

Answer (score 3):

Why are you collecting the data in a `List<string>` if all you need to do is write it to a text file?

You might as well just:

- Open the text file;
- Iterate over the records, appending each string to the text file (without storing the strings in memory);
- Flush and close the text file.

You will need far less memory than now, because you won't be keeping all those strings unnecessarily in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set some vmargs for memory!
Also... look into writing it straight to your file and not holding it in a List

Answer (score 1):

What Roy Dictus says sounds the best way.
Also you can try to add a limit to your query. So your database result won't be so large.

For info on:
[Limiting query size with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344493/limiting-query-size-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't read all records from database to list. It required a lot of memory. You an combine reading records and writing them to file. For example read 1000 records from db to list and save(append) them to text file, clear used memory (list.Clear()) and continue with new records.

Answer (score 0):

From several other topics on StackOverflow I read that the Entity Framework is not designed to handle bulk data like that. The EF will cache/track all data in the context and will cause the exception in cases of huge bulks of data. Options are to use SQL directly or split up your records in smaller sets.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the gc arraylist in VS c++ similar to the gc List that you used, to works fin with small and intermediate data sets, but when using Big Dat, same problem  'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
As the size of these gcs cannot exceed 2 GB and therefore become inefficient with Big data, I built my own linked list, which gives the same functionality, dynamic increase and get by index, basically, it is a normal linked list class, with a dynamic array inside to provide getting data by index, it duplicates the space, but you may delete the linked list after updating the array is you do not need it keeping only the dynamic array, this would solve the problem. see the code:

```
struct LinkedNode
{
    long data;
    LinkedNode* next;
};


class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    LinkedNode* head;
    long Count;
    long * Data;
    void add(long data);
    void update();
    //long get(long index);
};

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    this->Count = 0;
    this->head = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){
    LinkedNode * temp; 
    while(head){
        temp= this->head ;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    if (Data)
        delete [] Data; Data=NULL;
}

void LinkedList::add  (long data){
    LinkedNode * node = new LinkedNode();
    node->data = data;
    node->next = this->head;
    this->head = node;
    this->Count++;}

void LinkedList::update(){
    this->Data= new long[this->Count];
    long i = 0;
    LinkedNode * node =this->head;
    while(node){
        this->Data[i]=node->data;
        node = node->next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

If you use this, please refer to my work https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/big.2018.0064